# Do these messages in the LDAP log on OSX Mavericks Server mean anything?

Tags: macos, server.app, open-directory, ldap

```
Jan 26 06:23:05 server.mydoman.net slapd[329]: => bdb_idl_delete_key: c_get failed: DB_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Locker killed to resolve a deadlock (-30994)
Jan 26 06:23:05 server.mydoman.net slapd[329]: conn=4318 op=3: attribute "entryCSN" index delete failure
```

I see hundreds of these messages in the LDAP log.  are they significant at all?

Comment: How's your CPU usage and are you experiencing any LDAP issues?

Comment: Don't see any issues with CPU usage.  I've been having trouble with osx users with network user accounts and home folders on the server, which is why i started digging into server logs

Comment: Mobile homes which get synced or what kind?

Comment: Not using mobile homes.  I have mostly network users with local homes.  1 network user with a network home, but that is a test account.  I have been having trouble getting network homes to work well.  Preferences usually get lost, especially for mail.  Will keep asking for passwords over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

I found an entry in a thread on OpenLDAP.org's lists in which the commenter says that this is normal for BDB.

> This is a normal occurrence in BerkeleyDB and does not indicate an
> actual  error. The bdb/hdb backend code automatically retries when a
> BDB deadlock is  reported.
>
> Howard Chu, Chief Architect, OpenLDAP

(Source: https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-bugs/201409/msg00057.html)

I have been chasing the same error for the better part of a week, and a *lot* of people report this error for many different versions of macOS/MacOS and Linux, so it seems... normal, maybe?

Hope that helps.

/Bill